# EasyTag documentation

Tags: cd, easytag

Is there a manual for the EasyTag program for processing the ID tags on CD collections?  I can find lots of fragmented information but nothing like a single unified manual.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is horrible. There is a [german description](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EasyTAG/) with pictures. That was my entry point. You might have to brush up your german ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The one and only official manual:

https://help.gnome.org/users/easytag/stable/

Comment: That's the first thing I found, and I found it easily. But it says nothing I can see about the opening screen, which is why I'm confused.